# How can I create a sidebar in all my Django templates using CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

My problem is that I need dynamic tags list on all my pages and all posts (one post) content on that page too. How can I include tag sidebar on all the pages using Class Based Views? Thanks.

EDIT:
the tags list must be sorted by the frequency of using.
My code:

```
class AllTagCloudView(ListView):
    model = Tag
    template_name = 'tag_cloud.html'
    context_object_name = 'tag_cloud'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Tag.objects.values("name", "slug").annotate(Count("post")).order_by('-post__count')
        return qs
```

I've tried to use

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tag_cloud.html', takes_context=True)
def sidebar_sorted_tags(context):
```

but I don't understand how to do it to work.

Also I have tried to use {% include 'tag_cloud.html' %}:

```
<div>
    <p>Tags</p>
    {% for tag in tag_cloud %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/tag/{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.name }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    {% empty %}
        <a href="">There is no tags yet</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I think this is something stupid or I do something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is not related to class based views.  You need to use custom [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tag_cloud.html')
def sidebar_sorted_tags():
    return {'tag_cloud': Tag.objects.values("name", "slug")
                            .annotate(Count("post")).order_by('-post__count')}
```

And now in your `base.html` template write:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% sidebar_sorted_tags %}
```

Comment: I have tried to use it but don't understand how to realize it in my case.

Comment: See the updated answer.   `my_tags` is the name of your tags library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) and global base template that all of your other templates will [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends). Also you can use simple [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) in your template tag instead of global base template.

Comment: The using of 'include' rendered {% empty %} and I don't know how to render it right in this case.